# How to reuse a downloaded image in another activity?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-glide

I have already used Glide library to download an image, but I want to **reuse** that image in another activity without re downloading it again. How to do it?

I have tried to use `.diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)` but I didn't know what to do next..

```
Glide.with(activityContext)
                .load(posterURL)
                .into(holder.poster);
```

I was expecting that I could pass it as an extra data to intent as an image not as URL

Comment: You can convert posterURL to `String` and pass to another activity. Then from receiver class, you can convert it back to `URI`.

Comment: This idea is that I will have to download the image **again** after converting it to a URI which is something I don't want to do - @JohnJoe

Comment: No, you don't need to download it again. You just receive it from Sender class.

Comment: Okay I got it, but `.diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)` will not be used in that case, right? @JohnJoe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `.diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)` it will download it first time only.
Second time you load the image and use the same `URL` it will take it from `Cache`.

So just pass the `URL` to another `Activity` and use the same `Glide` code

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is exactly what I was looking for :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this via many way

1) Use the same URL in other Activity wherever you want to load the image with Glide as you are doing currently.

2) You can get bitmap from Glid and can write into the directory and save the path. And use the same file path to decode the image in other activity.

TO get bitmap via Glide use below code

```
   Glide.with(mContext)
        .asBitmap()
        .load("url")
        .into(new CustomTarget<Bitmap>() {
            @Override
            public void onResourceReady(@NonNull Bitmap resource, @Nullable Transition<? super Bitmap> transition) {
               //resource is the bitmap you can use
            }

            @Override
            public void onLoadCleared(@Nullable Drawable placeholder) {
            }
        });
```

NOTE: You can keep that resource bitmap and pass that bitmap to other Activity if you do not want to write to the file.

TO do that use below code

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, NewActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("BitmapImage", bitmap);
```

And to retrieve the image use below code

```
 Intent intent = getIntent(); 
 Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap) intent.getParcelableExtra("BitmapImage");
```

Important point is Bitmap implements Parcelable so it can be passed without any worry.

Comment: Pass bitmap is a bad practice. What if the bitmap is large?

Comment: yes you are right... but at least there is a way to do so :)